# Refused to load the script Error in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, same-origin-policy

I am getting the following error in Chrome when loading a page on my website, which and HTML5 page:

```
Refused to load the script 'data:application/x-javascript;base64,LyohICRGaWxlVmVyc2lvbj0xLjYuMTczICovIA…ExMTIyQTYyNjUzRjZDQzcyOEIwRjZFRjJGRkMxQ0E3QjU3OUY0RDIyNERBRDY0QUI2RDRFQUFD' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src https://*.facebook.com http://*.facebook.com https://*.fbcdn.net http://*.fbcdn.net *.facebook.net *.google-analytics.com *.virtualearth.net *.google.com 127.0.0.1:* *.spotilocal.com:* chrome-extension://lifbcibllhkdhoafpjfnlhfpfgnpldfl 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' https://*.akamaihd.net http://*.akamaihd.net".
```

Is there any way to solve this issue. I have full control over the server (Amazon EC2), so I can't make any changed necessary. Thanks